# Synchronised AKKA actor best practice

Tags: java, synchronization, akka, actor

I have the following requirement

I need to complete a major task

Actor A: Performs the major task, if the message is 'special' it passes it to actor B for processing and then finishes the task
Actor B : Performs special logical task for the major task and A and B together complete this A

The implementation

```
public static class ActorA extends UntypedActor {


  public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof Work) {
     // if message is special 
ActorRef actorB = this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ActorB.class,));
                actorB.tell(new specialTask(message.property), getSelf());

    } else {
      unhandled(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Actor B

```
 public static class ActorB extends UntypedActor {


      public void onReceive(Object message) {
        if (message instanceof specialTask) {
       //do special task using the message that does not change the state of the message

        } else {
          unhandled(message);
        }
      }
    }
```

ActorA does not depend of the completion in actor Bs task. But I am not sure if there should be no message passing betweeb actor B to A on its completion. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Working code should go to codeview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, posted http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150871/synchronised-akka-actor-best-practice

Comment: The question isnt accepted on coderview.stackexchange.com, so i will continue trying here. thanks

Comment: You are welcome ... consider deleting this one here then!

Comment: I meant it isnt accepted there so I will continue asking it here. I dont want my code reviewed as to if it will work, I just want to know the bst practice in situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you just want to use Actor B to compute something that shouldn't be computed in A. In this case, if A does not rely on results created by B, you don't really need to send a message from B to A when the computation is completed. You can just do whatever you want with the result of the computation in B (write to disk, post to another service, etc).

However it is a good practice to use an Akka pattern as [Work Pulling](https://speakerdeck.com/player/de13b56959864d8c9b5620239c931562?#) or a [Reactive Stream](http://pt.slideshare.net/Lightbend/understanding-akka-streams-back-pressure-and-asynchronous-architectures) to not overflow your actor B mailbox with messages from A. The main idea is to have Actor B asking for tasks.

Another thing to consider, if the B does any I/O/heavy work/blocking is highly recommended to put this actor to run in a separated [dispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html), otherwise it can shutdown your entire system.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the answer. Actor B does not perform blocking task, Can you point me to the pattern where you mean actors ask for tasks? If you are talking about the actor's ask method to send messages, that will return a future. However the parent actor does not care about the result returned by actor B

Comment: Hi. Not the ask pattern from Akka API. I just added the link to the Work Pulling pattern and the link about Reactive Stream, which is another alternative to handle the back pressure, considering the case in which your Actor A generates messages faster than B can handle it. But as far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your initial design. I just pointed that things out because it took me a while to figure out that I needed to use separated dispatchers for blocking calls and handle the mailbox overflow.

Comment: Got it, thank you for he explanation, it just seems weird that there is no acknowledgment to the sender after a message has ben processed